# VirtualBox vmdk keeps growing

Tags: virtualbox, vmdk

I have created a VM with a dynamically expanding disk - vmdk.

After a few weeks the space used in the VM stabilizes at around 45gb. On this VM there are a few jobs that create a great number of files but these are then also deleted.

The vmdk file on the host however keeps growing and growing. Until it uses all space available. 150gb.

Is this normal? How can I prevent this from happening? I have always used dynamically expanding disks but those machines have always been short lived. Should I use a fixed size disk for machines that I plan te keep running longer?

Comment: It seems to be normal. And deleting a file has no effect on the vmdks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your disk is set up to use "sparse" storage, which expands the disk actually used as necessary, so yes, to prevent this happening in future installations, you should configure the disk to be fixed size at configuration time.

VirtualBox supports sparse disk images, in fact they are called "dynamic" images and are the default. Deleting a file makes no size to the disk actually used as VirtualBox is operating at the block level, while the file is deleted at the filesystem level - and when a delete is done, space is simply marked as unused - the space is not actually zeroed out and made reclaimable.

Depending on your usage case and requirements, it might make sense for you to separate the data and OS, and store the data on NFS for similar, such that you centralise and have control of disk space at the file level - at the expense of slower IO and more complex setup.